# Two-way MANOVA - No significant multivariate interaction - can I still interpret univariate interaction?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, interaction, manova

Assume that a two-way mixed (two independent variables (IVs)) MANOVA was conducted. The multivariate interaction effect of the two IVs on the dependent variables (DPs) together was not significant. Can I still interpret a significant interaction on the univariate level? Are there some sources?

Comment: Multivariate analysis eats more degrees of freedom for the effects than univariate analyses. When, say, we have two groups which differ mostly by variable Y1 and barely by Y2, the test of the group difference will be more significant in Y1 univar. test than in the multivar. Y1 Y2 test - because of the df's spent. It is you who decide which test you follow in your conclusions. In the simple example I gave one would maybe just discard Y2 - seeing its weak contribution to the difference, and stay with Y1.

Comment: I added one detail to my question (mixed MANOVA). So lets say I have no significant interaction on the multivariate Level (Y1*Y2) on DV (collapsed over all DVs) then a common suggest is to continue with interpreting the main effects of the two separated IVs (Y1, Y2) on DV on the multivariate level. If they are significant go to the univariate level and search if the main effect of (Y1, Y2) on the DVs (seperated now) is significant. But if there is a significant interaction on the univariate level, can this effect be interpreted, even though, on the multivariate level there is no sig. interact?

Comment: Under header 7.6.1 in the book linked below, this (common suggest) procedure is explained. But I don't get it. Can we still interpret interaction effects on the univariate level, if the multivariate level interaction is insignificant or is this forbidden? https://books.google.de/books?id=W8Y0CwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Applied+Multivariate+Statistics+for+the+Social+Sciences&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz3er917rcAhXJEVAKHapJBWQQ6AEIMjAC#v=onepage&q=Applied%20Multivariate%20Statistics%20for%20the%20Social%20Sciences&f=false